# asm code containing %0,what does that mean?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86, inline-assembly

My asm knowledge is so limited, I need to know the following codes:

```
movl %%esp %0
```

Does `%0` represent a register, a memory address, or something else? What does the `%0` mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It represents some [input/output operand](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). It allows you to make use of your C variables in your assembly code. [This page](http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly) has some nice examples.

`%0` is just the first input/output operand defined in your code. In practice, this could be a stack variable, a heap variable or a register depending on how the assembly code generated by the compiler.

For example:

```
int a=10, b;
asm ("movl %1, %%eax; 
      movl %%eax, %0;"
     :"=r"(b)        /* output */
     :"r"(a)         /* input */
     :"%eax"         /* clobbered register */
     );
```

`%0` is `b` in this case and `%1` is `a`.

Comment: Is there something wrong"%0 is b in this case and %0 is a",two %0??

Comment: [Here](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) is one more "How To" with examples.